# Как сделать склейку домена когда в url адресе есть значения ХЭШ решетки #

Tags: редирект, http-status-code-301

Всем привет! такая проблема.
не могу склеить внутренние страницы, то есть, при запросе к определенной страницы, она открывается как со слешем так и без, пример https://site.ru/#service/ b https://site.ru/#service.
как сделать слейку или редирект что бы открывалась только в одном значение без слеша.

Код:

```
<!-- Nav-Links start -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="" class="scroll-to">Главная</a></li>
    <!-- <li><a href="#services2" class="scroll-to">Преимущества</a></li> -->
    <li class="active"><a href="price.html" ">Прайс</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services" class="scroll-to">Цены</a></li>   
    <li><a href="#locations" class="scroll-to">Контакты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll-to">Записаться</a></li>
    <!-- <li><a href="#newsletter" class="scroll-to">Вакансии</a></li> -->
</ul>
<!-- Nav-Links end -->
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: есть якорная ссылка на странице, она открывается как со слешем так и без слеша, то есть не идет редирект.  к примеру, https://site.ru/#service/  не перенаправляется на страницу без слеша. на такую  https://site.ru/#service